# How do I pass data from button to coffeescript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am a newbie to web development and have following basic question.

My Html looks like this:

```
<a class="btn-select" data-myId="10091" data-myDescr="The thing we delete">Click me!</a>
```

My coffee script looks like this:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.btn-select', ->
requestId = $(this).data('myId');
alert 'hello ' + requestId;
```

But when I click the button, I get "hello undefined". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 data-attrs are required by the spec to be lowercase.

Use: `$(this).data('myid')`

http://jsfiddle.net/6RW79/